# How do I enable Two Factor Authentication for users access to Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

First of all, is it possible to turn on 2FA for user access into google analytics? I want to make it more secure for users in my organization to access Google Analytics and mitigate risks of data leaks.

Reason being is that staff use business emails managed by Outlook servers and then they create google accounts which are used to access GA4. Issue is, it is a large organization and when they leave - I do not get informed. This leads to the issue that they can still retain their access to the GA data as whilst their email access is removed, they can still login to GA using the email as the username.

Currently I run a quarterly audit to remove access to people I find have left the organization (usually a bounced email or non-reply is how I determine). However, there must be a better way than this and I'm interested if anyone out there might have some suggestions on this.